# Change a form select from multiple to flat dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, select

I am using a plugin in Wordpress (taxonomy-picker) that allow me to search by multiple taxonomies.

I want to change two of the items that are "multiple" to flat type but I have to do this dynamically.

So right now I have for example:

```
<select name="bebida[]" multiple=""><option value="bebida=tp-all">Todos</option><option value="bebida=batidos" class="parent">Batidos</option><option value="bebida=cervezas" class="parent">Cervezas</option><option value="bebida=cervezas-importacion" class="parent">Cervezas Importación</option><option value="bebida=cocktail" class="parent">Cocktail</option><option value="bebida=copas" class="parent">Copas</option><option value="bebida=copas-premium" class="parent">Copas Premium</option><option value="bebida=gin-tonic" class="parent">Gin Tonic</option><option value="bebida=licores" class="parent">Licores</option><option value="bebida=vinos" class="parent">Vinos</option><option value="bebida=zumos" class="parent">Zumos</option></select>
```

That is created dynamically and I want to delete the multiple="" attribute in order to make them flat only for some of the selects that only have a "name" but not a class.

Is posible to do this??

Also I am not sure of how can I add a different class only to the attributes I want.

So I want to know how can I add a class with the name I want and delete multiple attr to ONLY the selects I want dynamically.

So for example I want to say something like:

"If select name is "bebida[]" add class "bebida" and delete the attribute multiple" and also "If the select name is "ambiente[] add class "ambiente" (but no delete anything)."

I am trying something like this to delete the multiple selector but looks like is not working:

> $("select[name='localizacion[]']").removeAttr('multiple');

Thank you so much.

- Edited with more information

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time, please make an effort and post your JS code, even if it's not working. You'll get better responses and learn more if you do.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress ships with jQuery, so (inside document.ready):

```
$('select').each(function() {
  if ( $(this).attr('name') == "bebida[]" && $(this).attr('class') == "bebida" ) {
    $(this).removeAttr('multiple');
  }
});
```

Syntax probably isn't dead on, but you get the idea.

Comment: Hello, how can I tell to that script that I want to remove de attr multiple only to the select name ="bebida[]" and the same to tell that I want a class called for example "bebida" to only that select. I mean, all the different select boxes are created dynamically (10) so with that code I asume that will delete the attr to all the selects but no only to the one I want. Thank you so much!

Comment: Answer updated to check for the name and class values that you specified. Previously it was looking for selects with a name and no class, as your question originally stated.